# /var/www - not parse php code

Tags: apache2, php

I added php file to /var/www/ but not working (not parse PHP code):

> http://site.com/a.php

```
<?php

echo "work";

?>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you installed php and is php enabled on the server?

Comment: @zwets yes, it's enabled